# Unable to test debounced Backbone view event

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js, mocha.js, sinon

When I am not throttling/debouncing the function the test passes.

However when I debounce the event to prevent flooding the server the test no longer passes. Mocha outputs `AssertionError: expected execute to have been called at least once, but it was never called`

It should be noted that the debounced call works without errors in the live code. Which is why I'm thoroughly confused why the test fails.

**The Test:**

```
describe('When information is entered into the search fields', function () {
    it('vents up the search:for:churches command', function () {
        var executeStub = sinon.stub(App, 'execute');

        view = new SearchForm()
        view.render();

        view.$el.find('input[name=church_name]').val('baptist')
        view.$el.find('input[name=zip]').val('61615')

        view.$el.find('input[name=zip]').trigger($.Event('keypress'))

        expect(executeStub).to.have.been.called

        view.close();
        PEP.execute.restore()
    });
});
```

**Un-throttled:**

```
var SearchForm = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({

    template: 'search_form',
    events: {
        'keypress [data-search-field]' : 'searchForChurches'
    },

    searchForChurches: function() {
        console.log('not debounced')
        var searchData = Backbone.Syphon.serialize(this);
        App.execute("search:for:churches", searchData);
    }

});
```

**Throttled:**

```
var SearchForm = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({

    template: 'search_form',
    events: {
        'keypress [data-search-field]' : 'searchForChurches'
    },

    searchForChurches: _.debounce(function() {
        console.log('debounced')
        var searchData = Backbone.Syphon.serialize(this);
        App.execute("search:for:churches", searchData);
    }, 200)

});
```

**Edit:**
*I have also posted a related follow-up question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21167488/how-to-test-a-debounced-throttled-backbone-view-event-with-mocha-to-ensure-its-a*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simon's approach worked great for most cases but I kept bumping into different situations that were causing more errors. After spending more time with it and looking at sinon's documentation I think I have a better approach.

Sinon's [Fake Timers](http://sinonjs.org/releases/v2.3.8/fake-timers/) to the rescue.

```
describe('When information is entered into the search fields', function () {
    it('vents up the search:for:churches command', function () {
        var clock = sinon.useFakeTimers();
        var executeStub = sinon.stub(App, 'execute');

        view = new SearchForm()
        view.render();

        view.$el.find('input[name=church_name]').val('baptist')
        view.$el.find('input[name=zip]').val('61615')

        view.$el.find('input[name=zip]').trigger($.Event('keypress'))
        clock.tick(200)

        expect(executeStub).to.have.been.called

        view.close();
        PEP.execute.restore()
        clock.restore()    
    });
});
```

Answer (score 8):

There is a problem, when using *UnderscoreJS* with *SinonJS*.

- The *debounce* function in *UnderscoreJS* uses *_.now*.
- *SinonJS* covers the *Date* object, but doesn't cover *_.now*.

For testing purposes, i replace *_.now* in the test's bootstrap file:

```
_.now = function() {
  return new Date().getTime();
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Throttling anything means the execution will be asynchronous. This is why it fails in your tests, because the `App.execute` method is not call right away, so when you assert it have been called, it haven't yet.

In this case, don't use Sinon. Just manually stub your method:

```
describe('When information is entered into the search fields', function () {
    it('vents up the search:for:churches command', function (done) {
        var originalMethod = App.prototype.execute;

        App.prototype.execute = function () {
            App.prototype.execute = originalMethod;
            done(); // calling done will pass the test, otherwise it'll fail with a timeout
        };

        view = new SearchForm()
        view.render();

        view.$el.find('input[name=church_name]').val('baptist')
        view.$el.find('input[name=zip]').val('61615')

        view.$el.find('input[name=zip]').trigger($.Event('keypress'))

        view.close();
    });
});
```